# Are "thinking" and "while thinking" the same thing?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure, but in some situation both seem to mean the same thing. Is it? I feel "thinking" implies that you are doing it now so "while" is redundant. If that's the case, why would you use "while"?

For example:

> He was laughing while thinking at the things you said yesterday.
>
> He was laughing thinking at the things you said yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is more grammatical. It separates both actions to make it clearer.

The second one is a little bit informal.

You can say "**He was driving texting on his phone**" people would understand you although it isn't correct. It would be better to say **"He was driving *while* texting on his phone"**.